# SQL - Last 6 months (12,18,24,30) divisor by 6 months query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

OK, I'm writing a stored procedure for a report and I need every person with there last sale date in a divisor of 6, example - when the report runs it will use todays date as the date and anyones whos last sale date is exactly 6 months or 12 months or 18 months from todays date should be returned in the stored procedure.

My initial thinking was to use a where clause with;

```
WHERE LastSaleDate = DATEADD(m, -6, @Date)
   OR LastSaleDate = DATEADD(m, -12, @Date)...
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: If you want increments of 6, it seems that you will need separate queries and a `pivot`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could join a list of dates in 6 month increments. Without your full DDL I can't create a full query, but you should be able to using something like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    T
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  [Date] = DATEADD(MONTH, - Number, @Date)
            FROM    Master..spt_values
            WHERE   Type = 'P'
            AND     Number % 6 = 0
        ) D
            ON D.Date = T.LastSalesDate
```

Comment: That would work, excellent, thanks! One addition would be if it was within 2 weeks of the date e.g. DATEADD(MONTH, -Number, (@Date+14)), is that possible?

Comment: If I understand the problem right you could change the join condition to `ON T.LastSalesDate BETWEEN DATEADD(WEEK, -2, D.Date) AND DATEADD(WEEK, 2, D.Date)`